# Yii2 PHP Excel Error getAttributeLabel() on null

Tags: php, yii2

I have to implementing export excel using moonland PHP excel extension.  When I implemented it, it throws the error:

> "Call to a member function getAttributeLabel() on null".

**Code**

```
  $dataProvider = new \app\models\Details;

     \moonland\phpexcel\Excel::widget([
                'models' => $dataProvider,
                'mode' => 'export', //default value as 'export'
                'columns' => ['id','name','address'], //without header working, because the header will be get label from attribute label.
                //'header' => ['id' => 'Header Column 1','name' => 'Header Column 2', 'address' => 'Header Column 3'],
            ]);
```

**My model**

```
class Details extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'details';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'required'],
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'address'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
      /*  return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'name' => Yii::t('app', 'Name'),
            'address' => Yii::t('app', 'Address'),
        ];*/
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'address' =>'Address',
        ];
    }
}
```

**Table**

[image]

May i know what is the problem in that, thanks in advance for your idea

Comment: What does `get_class_methods($dataProvider);` before yhe usage in `\moonland\phpexcel\Excel`?

Comment: What is this : `$dataProvider = new \app\models\Details;` ?? And you should use models from a dataprovider object like this : `'models' => $dataProvider->getModels(),`

Comment: can you give some brief explanation in coding for better understand

Comment: i have follow as per your mentioned way, but here we got some other issue, i was updated my question with table structure a. if i opened the file in notepad and remove the first space then open it with excel means its working fine, do you have any idea to resolve my problem

Comment: Normally, $dataProvider should be:  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider('query' => Details:find());   Check \moonland\phpexcel\Excel, what does it use.